# How do I retrieve two values from my JSON url file with JQuery and apply on Html?

Tags: jquery, json

I'm new to jQuery and Json and I'm trying to make a quiz.

My problem right now is to retrieve `incorrect_answers` and `correct_answer` from Json url file and have them display as answer options for the questions. I'm stuck right now and I'm helpful for all the tips and answers.

```
 **Json** 

{
  "response_code": 0,
  "results": [
    {
      "category": "History",
      "type": "multiple",
      "difficulty": "medium",
      "question": "What disease crippled President Franklin D. Roosevelt and led him to help the nation find a cure? ",
      "correct_answer": "Polio",
      "incorrect_answers": [
        "Cancer",
        "Meningitis",
        "HIV"
      ]
    },
    {
      "category": "Science: Computers",
      "type": "multiple",
      "difficulty": "easy",
      "question": "What does the Prt Sc button do?",
      "correct_answer": "Captures what&#039;s on the screen and copies it to your clipboard",
      "incorrect_answers": [
        "Nothing",
        "Saves a .png file of what&#039;s on the screen in your screenshots folder in photos",
        "Closes all windows"
      ]
    },
    {
      "category": "Entertainment: Video Games",
      "type": "multiple",
      "difficulty": "medium",
      "question": "Which puzzle game was designed by a Russian programmer, featuring Russian buildings and music?",
      "correct_answer": "Tetris",
      "incorrect_answers": [
        "Jenga",
        "Boulder Dash",
        "Puzzled"
      ]
    },
    {
      "category": "Geography",
      "type": "multiple",
      "difficulty": "hard",
      "question": "Where is the fast food chain &quot;Panda Express&quot;    headquartered?",
      "correct_answer": "Rosemead, California",
      "incorrect_answers": [
        "Sacremento, California",
        "Fresno, California",
        "San Diego, California"
      ]
    },
    {
      "category": "Entertainment: Video Games",
      "type": "multiple",
      "difficulty": "easy",
      "question": "In what year was Hearthstone released?",
      "correct_answer": "2014",
      "incorrect_answers": [
        "2011",
        "2013",
        "2012"
      ]
    }



**Html**
```

```
  <h2>History Quiz</h2>

<a href="#">Start the Quiz</a>
```

```
<h2>Question:</h2>

<ul>
  <li></li>
</ul>

<a href="#">Submit</a>

 <div id="next-question"></div>
```

```
  **jQuery**

$(function () {
    var start = $('.start');
    var quiz = $('.quiz');

    var questionIndex = 0;
    var questionData = [];

    start.on('click', function() {
            start.hide();
            quiz.show();
            seeQuestion();
            createRadioButton();
    });

    function seeQuestion() {
        var questions = questionData[questionIndex];

        $('.quiz h2').text(questions.question);//question is viewed in h2
        console.log(questions);

        $('.quiz ul').html(' ');
        //code for the answers
    };

    // create buttons
    function createRadioButton() {
        for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
             $('<input type="radio" name="dynradio" />').appendTo('.quiz  ul ');
        };
    };

    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/9ocrl',
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'get',
        cache: false,

        success: function(data) {
             $(data.results).each(function(key, value) {
                 questionData.push(value);
             });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse JSON in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935632/parse-json-in-javascript)

Comment: console.log(questionData.incorrect_answers); is showing me undefined. What do i need to do for get the right result?

Comment: You would have to use something like `questionData[index].incorrect_answers`, with 0 <= `index` <= questionData.length-1.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this snippet.

```js
// data variable that will be "filled" when the
// API request resolves with data
let data

// containers and "active" parts
const question = document.getElementById('question');
const answers = document.getElementById('answers');
const btnNext = document.getElementById('next');

// self calling async function
(async function() {
  // fetching data from the API and waiting for the
  // returned Promise to resolve (or reject)
  // data = await getDataFromAPI()

  // with $.getJSON()
  data = await getJSONData()
  console.log('data', data)
  // activating the next button that is disabled
  // on initial load
  btnNext.removeAttribute('disabled')
})();

// actual function to get data from API
function getDataFromAPI() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fetch('https://api.myjson.com/bins/9ocrl')
      .then(r => r.json())
      .then(r => resolve(r))
      .catch(err => reject(err))
  })
}

// using $.getJSON() to retrieve data from the API endpoint
function getJSONData() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    jQuery.getJSON('https://api.myjson.com/bins/9ocrl', function(response) {
      resolve(response)
    })
  })
}

// counter - to keep track of current question
var currentQuestionId = 0


// next question code
btnNext.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if (data.results.length > currentQuestionId) {

    displayQuestion(currentQuestionId)
    currentQuestionId++
  } else {
    displayFinish()
    currentQuestionId = 0
  }
})

function displayQuestion(questionId) {
  question.textContent = data.results[currentQuestionId].question

  // you can define the answer templates here
  // (e.g. add radiobuttons or something)
  let html = ''
  createAnswers(currentQuestionId).forEach((e, i) => {
    html += `<li>Answer ${i}: ${e}</li>`
  })
  answers.innerHTML = html
}

function displayFinish() {
  answers.innerHTML = ''
  question.textContent = 'You\'ve finished the quiz!'
}

// creating the array for the answers
function createAnswers(questionId) {
  // you can randomize the answer order here (for example)
  return [data.results[questionId].correct_answer, ...data.results[questionId].incorrect_answers]
}
```

```css
.disabled {}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="next" disabled>NEXT</button>

<div id="question"></div>
<ul id="answers">

</ul>
```

## EDIT

The snippet above had to be modified to use **$.getJSON()** instead of **fetch()**.

I left both solutions in the snippet, but the used / working one is **$.getJSON()**.

Comment: Thank you, does it work if i replace **data** with my own **questionData** or do i need to create a function to retrive data from the url first? @muka.gergely

Comment: I have to edit the answer so it works with your **AJAX** request.

Comment: OK, now it fetches data from the API you set in your example, waits for it, and then the "NEXT" button activates and you can start with your questions and answers

Comment: Would appreciate it alot if you could @muka.gergely. I'm reading and watching alot videos and text to try to learn but cant find anywhere.

Comment: Thank you from bottom of my heart @muka.gergely

Comment: I'm really happy to help :)

Comment: **var data;

    $.getJSON('https://api.myjson.com/bins/9ocrl', function(data) {
    data = data;
    });**                                                                                                                     I Get this answer when I try to **console.log(data); Unable to get property 'results' of undefined or null reference.**  **How can i do with  $.getJSON() like you are doing with fetch? **@muka.gergely

Comment: Your problem with `$.getJSON()` seemed to be that you called the response **data** in your function, and that overwrote the **data** variable outside (it was a variable scope problem). I edited the snippet to use the `$.getJSON()` function, but I still do think that you should use `fetch()` instead. The snippet seems to work well with the new function built in.